# What is the purpose of using "next" to iterate over a 1-tuple?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a question about the Python code below, which is copied from Appendix A of paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1305.1878.

What happens in the line `M=next(XD+XD.T for XD in (self.X.dot(Derivative()),))`?

Why is using the in-built function `next()` needed here?

```
class singleNeutrinoSolution(object):
    '''Most likely neutrino momentum for tt-->lepton+jets'''
    def __init(self, b , mu, #Lorentz vectors
               metX, metY,   #Momentum imbalance
               sigma2,          #Momentum imlance unc. 2X2 matrix
              mW2=mW**2,mT2=mT**2):
        self.solutionSet=nuSolutionSet(b,mu,mW2,mT2)
        S2=np.vstack([np.vstack([np.linalg.inv(sigma2),[0,0]]).T,[0,0,0]])
        V0 = np.outer([metX, metY, 0], [0, 0, 1])
        deltaNu=V0-self.solutionSet.H
        self.X=np.dot(deltaNu.T,S2).dot(deltaNu)
        M=next(XD+XD.T for XD in (self.X.dot(Derivative()),))
        solutions=intersection_ellipses(M,UnitCircle())
        self.solutions=sorted(solutions,key=self.calcX2)
    def calcX2(self,t):
        return np.dot(t,self.X).dot(t)
    @property
    def chi2(self):
        return self.calcX2(self.solutions[0])
    @property
    def nu(self):
        '''Solution for neutrino momentum'''
        return self.solutionSet.H.dot(self.solution[0])
```

Comment: Do you know what the `next` function does?

Comment: Concerning (3): Why do you think that?

Comment: Concerning (2): The `key` argument must be a *callable* (e.g. a method).

Comment: I'm going to remove questions (2) and (3), because on Stack Overflow there should be only one question per post, and (1) seems the most interesting.

Comment: BTW, `__init` should be `__init__`.

Answer (score 1):

In this line,

> ```
> M=next(XD+XD.T for XD in (self.X.dot(Derivative()),))
> ```

the author wanted to reuse the result of `self.X.dot(Derivative())` in an expression as the variable `XD` twice.

The `next` function returns the first value from an iterable, which in this case is a single-iteration loop (a generator expression) over a single-item tuple,

```
(self.X.dot(Derivative()),)
```

where `self.X.dot(Derivative())` is the only item. Using a loop has the side effect of assigning the name `XD` to the current value of the iterable.

The author could have simply written

```
XD = self.X.dot(Derivative())
M = XD + XD.T
```

but they thought they were too "clever" for this.

Answer (score 1):

As the generator reveals, the result of the expression `self.X.dot(Derivative())` is needed two times, `XD` and `XD.T`. So the whole `next` + generator expression could also be written as two statements (which is a lot clearer):

```
XD = self.X.dot(Derivative())
M = XD + XD.T
```

Perhaps the authors wanted to save one line of code, but if that results in obfuscation like the presented `next` approach, this is a bad idea regarding readability (lines of code is generally a bad measure for code quality).

Note that starting with Python 3.9, you could also use an assignment expression<sup>(1)</sup>:

```
M = (XD := self.X.dot(Derivative())) + XD.T
```

but I don't recommend it either. The two statements version is the most readable and that counts the most (especially when published as part of an academic paper).

---

<sup>(1) It's not exactly the same, since the assignment expression will leak `XD` into the local namespace while the generator won't (as it uses its own namespace).</sup>